# LISP: formatting the output of read-line while reading a game board from a file

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to read the board from a text file, but while printing it is also printing the newline and inverted commas as:

```
(with-open-file (stream "brd1.txt")
  (do ((line (read-line stream nil)
             (read-line stream nil)))
      ((null line))
    (print line)))

"+ + +^M"
" 3 3 ^M"
"+ + +^M"
"     ^M"
"+ + +"
NIL
```

I am new to LISP. Could somebody help me to format these lines to print the exact board as:

```
+ + +
 3 3
+ + +

+ + +
```

Comment: try using format instead of print

Comment: Please post code, not pictures.

Answer (score 7):

## Input

Apparently you're trying to feed a DOS text file with CRLF-delimited lines to a Lisp implementation that assumes the lines to be LF-delimited in the Unix fashion.  Note that `read-line` *strips the newlines*, so in our case LF's are stripped, but CR's are treated as ordinary characters and thus remain in the string.

Newlines are platform specific and hence implementation dependent in Lisp.  What's more, it seems that neither asdf nor asdf-encodings address this issue.  The way I see it you have the following options:

- trim the CR's manually e. g. like this:

  `(string-right-trim '(\#Return) line)`
- use one of asdf's functions `slurp-stream-string` and `slurp-stream-lines`;
- use some implementation specific mechanism to specify the encoding;
- convert your text file to the Unix format.

## Output

As already noted, PRINT is actually a human-readable serialisation.  There is a bunch of printing functions on CLHS's page for WRITE and, of course, FORMAT.  In order to output a string you can also use WRITE-STRING (without appending a newline) or WRITE-LINE (with a newline).

UPD

Actually UIOP (not ASDF!) exports the utility function UIOP:STRIPLN, which does the following, according to its docstring:

> "Strip a string X from any ending CR, LF or CRLF.
>   Return two values, the stripped string and the ending that was stripped,
>   or the original value and NIL if no stripping took place.
>   Since our STRCAT accepts NIL as empty string designator,
>   the two results passed to STRCAT always reconstitute the original string"

Comment: Thankyou.
I was using a DOS text file. Converting it to UNIX format helped.

Comment: I want to implement best first search on this board game. Could you    suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm), `print` "produces output suitable for input to read". Use [format](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm) instead:

```
(format t "~a" line)
```

Comment: But it is not removing the newline ^M .

Also it is not printing it as a board instead printing everything in one line. Any suggestions?